# Overwrite an element at a specific position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a list and this list should remove the old element, but only for the element where the ID also matches. What is the best way to do this. The only thing I have so far is to delete the element. But is there no better option to just overwrite the item instead of deleting it?

The important thing is that the element should stay in the same place.

This is my list

```
const [days, setDays] = useState( 
[
  {
    id: 1,
    day: 'Monday'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    day: 'Sunday'
  }

])
```

This are my parameters

```
const day = 'Friday' 
const id = 2
```

And the expected output

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    day: 'Monday'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    day: 'Friday'
  }

]
```

What I tried

```
const newDay = {
  id: id,
  day: day
};
setDays((days) => [
      ...days.map((day) =>
        day.id=== id ? newDay: day
      ),
    ]);
```

Comment: That looks like it *should* work, though the `days.map` is sufficient enough to create the new array reference. What is the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you wanting to remove an element from the array, or replace one? It's rather unclear what you are asking for or really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem with the following code:

```
let result = days.map(item => (item.id === newday.id ? newday : item));
```

See my Stackblitz for full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5r74df?file=script.js